# Android video recording in loop

Tags: android, loops, video, media, record

I want to make an app, that will have an feature of recording in a loop. That means, app will continuously record video and when a user hits "end of recording" button, the video will have only the last 1 minute recorded. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no simple way to achieve this. Some rough ideas, though, in order of increasing difficulty:

- If you can safely assume that the total recording time will be fairly short (i.e., you won't run out of storage space on the device), you could record the entire video and then perform a post-processing step that trims the video to size.
- Record the video in one-minute chunks. When the user stops recording, compute how much of the previous chunk you need to prepend to the current chunk. Stitch the chunks together.
- Register as a [`PreviewCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) and store the video frames in your own file format. Periodically remove the frames that you don't care about because they're too old. You would need to store the audio separately, and then you would need to transcode the custom format into a standard format.

Each of these would probably require some NDK code to do the work efficiently.